# Changing iframe src redirects to homepage

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

First off this is the code

```
<div id="channelmiddle" class="middle-content alignleft">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changechannel(ch)
    {
        var url = "ch"+ch+".html";
        document.getElementById("channelchange").src = "ch"+ch+".html";
    }
    </script>
    <center>
    <button class="button_static" onclick="changechannel(1)">Channel 1</button>
    <button class="button_static" onclick="changechannel(2)">Channel 2</button>
    <button class="button_static" onclick="changechannel(3)">Channel 3</button>
    <button class="button_static" onclick="changechannel(4)">Channel 4</button>
    <button class="button_static" onclick="changechannel(5)">Channel 5</button>
    </center>
    <iframe id="channelchange" src="ch1.html" onLoad="alert('123')" width="500" height="400" scrolling="no"></iframe>

</div>
```

On this page, whenever I click the button, it redirects to the homepage. I can't figure out why. Can someone help me? do you need more information about the code?

Answer (score 1):

The modern browsers have security checks built in to prevent iframes from displaying web content when you change the src attribute. Chrome has a feature bypass the feature using &output=embed. [See this article](http://www.rivercitystudio.com/blog/2011/09/google-maps-embedding-x-frame-options-change/). From my tests, you can change the src attribute, but the content will not change. The best thing you can do is to load the iframe on the initial page load and not change the src attribute. There are a few solutions.

1. Make a redesign. Load the iframe with the content that needs to be displayed without the use of button clicks.
2. Send the user to another page. Set the iframe's src with the url that corresponds to the button on the initial page load.
3. If you absolutely have to, try making iframes for each url hide the iframe based on button clicks. This is not an ideal solution, but it accomplishes your goal.